# Converting from string to character

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, char, ascii

Q:

When i convert from `string` to `character` through the following line of code.

```
 grp.EntireClass = char.Parse(record[3]);
```

I get the following value:: `49'1'`

---

- Firstly why the ascii appear as a
  part of the value?
- Secondly how to get only the `'1'`
  part?

Comment: Is it _really_ necessary to parse a string to a character?  You have the string already, just access the `i`th character that you want, problem solved.

Comment: Using the string indexer you are already accessing a char.

Comment: because the field of type character in the database

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you are doing, so that people may explain how it is wrong.

Comment: simply i have a field of type character in the database and i try to convert the string to char to fill this field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you don't *actually* get "49'1'" - that's probably just how the debugger's showing it.

A simpler way though is:

```
string text = record[3]; // I assume...
grp.EntireClass = text[0]; // Gets the first character of text
```

This is equivalent to:

```
grp.EntireClass = record[3][0];
```

I split it out in the first version just for clarity.

You may well want to check that text is not:

- Null
- Empty
- More than one character

In the first two cases the above code will throw an exception; in the third case it would just ignore everything after the first character.

Comment: yeah the value is through the debugger

Comment: If that is the case, the answer is simply `char c = (char)record[3];`.

Comment: @Kobi: Maybe, maybe not. The OP isn't really being clear about this :(

Comment: You are probably correct in the first sentence - this is how the debugger displays the char `'1'`, so no string manipulation is needed.

Comment: @Kobi: We don't know, because he *is* calling `char.Parse`, so `record[3]` could be a string.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of *record* and *record[3]* ? If record is a string, why call Parse at all - you can just read record[3] and it would be a char. If record[3] itself is a string, use record[3][0] (for example).

Comment: @just_name: Eugene didn't ask about EntireClass; he asked about record.

Comment: @just_name Then, as Jon Skeet wrote, add some checks for non-null and string length, then access record[3][0] without any parsing.